# retrieve output from external command

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have a command

`commande = "cmd /c sc query state= all | findstr SERVICE_NAME | find /c /I "&LISTENER&"$"`

and I want to retrieve content to treat later in my script.

Comment: Another question but [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23479974/3439404)

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`WshScriptExec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object for that, so you can read its [`StdOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property upon completion:

```vb
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set cmd = sh.Exec("...")

Do While cmd.Status <> 1
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

output = cmd.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Comment: thank you but what is the utility of this part of the code ?

`Do While cmd.Status <> 1
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop`

that's if the command returns several values ?

Comment: @Galene `Exec` runs the command asynchronously, so you have to wait until it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adapted version of a complex script (stolen from [original documentation  by Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye284tb8(v=vs.84).aspx)). It grabs both `StdOut` and `StdErr` streams from executed command prompt window:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0

Dim strResult
myCmdExec "%comspec% /C dir /B /AD xxw*"
myCmdExec "%comspec% /C dir /B /AD fil*"
myCmdExec "cmd /c sc query state= all | findstr SERVICE_NAME  | find /I /c ""pcasvc"""
myCmdExec "cmd /c sc query state= all | findstr SERVICE_NAME | findstr /I ler$"

Private Sub myCmdExec( commande)
    strResult = commande & vbNewLine

    Dim WshShell, oExec, xExitCode, input, allInput
    allInput = ""

    Set WshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell")
    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec( commande)
    Do While True
         input = ReadAllFromAny( oExec)
         If input = -1 Then
              If oExec.Status = 1 Then Exit Do
              WScript.Sleep 100
         Else
              allInput = allInput & input
         End If
    Loop
    xExitCode = oExec.ExitCode

    If xExitCode <> 0 Then strResult = strResult & "Warning: Non-zero "
    strResult = strResult & "exit code " & CStr( xExitCode) & vbNewLine _
      & String( 30, "-") & vbNewLine 

    Wscript.Echo strResult & allInput & String( 30, "=") & vbNewLine
End Sub

Function ReadAllFromAny( oExec)
     If Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
          ReadAllFromAny = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll
          Exit Function
     End If
     If Not oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream Then
          ReadAllFromAny = oExec.StdErr.ReadAll
          Exit Function
     End If
     ReadAllFromAny = -1
End Function
```

**Output**:

```
==>cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\30320862.vbs

%comspec% /C dir /B /AD xxw*
Warning: Non-zero exit code 1
------------------------------
File Not Found
==============================

%comspec% /C dir /B /AD fil*
exit code 0
------------------------------
files
==============================

cmd /c sc query state= all | findstr SERVICE_NAME  | find /I /c "pcasvc"
exit code 0
------------------------------
1
==============================

cmd /c sc query state= all | findstr SERVICE_NAME | findstr /I ler$
exit code 0
------------------------------
SERVICE_NAME: Spooler
SERVICE_NAME: TrustedInstaller
==============================

==>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Service")

For Each objItem in colItems
    If Lcase(objitem.Name) = "audiosrv" Then
        msgbox objitem.name & " " & objitem.status  & " " & objitem.state
        objitem.StartService
    End If
Next
```

Is a better way to do what you want.

**Output**

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
Audiosrv OK Running
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```